# Errors relating to MatrixFunction

Tags: functions, matrix, warning-messages

I ran this and got some errors. Does anyone know how to solve this?
First I want to caluclate `A^2(A+I)` with `A =  {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}`.

```
MatrixFunction[#^2.(# + IdentityMatrix[3]) &, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, -1}}]
```

*StringForm::sfr: Item 1 requested in "Cannot compute the matrix function for the function 1." out of range; 0 items available.
MatrixFunction::nosol: Cannot compute the matrix function for the function 1.*

Second, I want to calculate `A2^k`:

```
A2= {{-0.5, 3}, {0, -0.8}};
MatrixFunction[#^k &, A2] // 
  FullSimplify[#, k > 0 && k \[Element] Integers] & // MatrixForm
```

*MatrixFunction::fnnum: Unable to compute the matrix function because the function #1^k& at a numeric value is not numeric.*

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can't have a matrix in the pure function in the first example. Use MatrixPower instead for the second example.

Comment: @chuy I updated the post

Comment: @CarlWoll I want to make a pure function `#^2(#+I)` where `I` is the identiy matrix. So how can I make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}];
MatrixFunction[#^2 (# + 1) &, A] == A . A . (A + IdentityMatrix[3])
(*    True    *)
```

You need to use the number 1, not the unit matrix, in the definition of the function for [`MatrixFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixFunction.html). As the documentation states,

> For convergent power series, `MatrixFunction[f,m]` effectively evaluates the power series for the function `f` with ordinary powers replaced by matrix powers.

For the second case, as @CarlWoll says, use [`MatrixPower`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html):

```
A2 = {{-0.5, 3}, {0, -0.8}};
MatrixPower[A2, k]
(*    {{0. + 1. (-0.5)^k, -10. (-0.8)^k + 10. (-0.5)^k},
       {0.,               0. + 1. (-0.8)^k}}                *)
```

For some reason, `MatrixFunction[#^k &, A2]` does not seem to work if `k` is unspecified, even though the exact calculation works without a problem:

```
A2 = {{-1/2, 3}, {0, -4/5}};
MatrixFunction[#^k &, A2]
(*    {{(-1/2)^k, 5 (-1)^k 2^(1 - k) + (-1)^(1 + k) 2^(1 + 2 k) 5^(1 - k)},
       {0,        (-4/5)^k}}                                                   *)
```

Comment: This would be complete  if  why ` MatrixFunction[#^k &, A2]` does not work is answered.

Comment: @anhnha see update

Comment: could you add the why the exact numbers make it work?

Comment: If I knew, I would have.